# Get the counts from 3 table tree scenario

Tags: mysql, join, count

```
table 1 - company
|id|name|
| -------- | -------------- |
|1|Company A|
|2|Company B|

table 2 - executives
|1d|name|company_id|
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
|1|Emp A|1|
|2|Emp B|1|
|3|Emp C|2|

table 3 - customers
|id|name|executive_id|
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
|1|Client A|1|
|2|Client B|1|
|3|Client C|2|
|4|Client D|3|
```

Now I need an mysql statement which can get

| Company name | No of Customers |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | 3 |
| Company B | 1 |

I am trying to get using LEFT JOIN and Counts

Please help

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOINS would also show company without executoves and customers

INNER JOIN only thoe with customers and executives

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO company
  (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Company A'),
  ('2', 'Company B');

CREATE TABLE executives (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(5),
  `company_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO executives
  (`id`, `name`, `company_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Emp A', '1'),
  ('2', 'Emp B', '1'),
  ('3', 'Emp C', '2');

CREATE TABLE customers (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(8),
  `executive_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO customers
  (`id`, `name`, `executive_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Client A', '1'),
  ('2', 'Client B', '1'),
  ('3', 'Client C', '2'),
  ('4', 'Client D', '3');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
c.`name` as  'Company name' , COUNT(*) AS 'No of Customers'
FROM company c
LEFT JOIN executives e ON e.company_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN customers cu ON cu.executive_id = e.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```

| Company name | No of Customers |
| --- | --- |
| Company A | 3 |
| Company B | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msScT6B5F7FjU2aQXVr2da/8)